# Select a specific band in GRASS (QGIS)

Tags: python, grass-gis, band

In GDAL you can use flags like

```
-b 1 -b 2
```

to select individual bands from a multiband raster

In Arc you can sometimes use "...\whatever.tif\Band_1" to select an individual band

Can you do similar in GRASS somehow? PyQGIS or otherwise

Comment: What are you trying to do next?

Comment: All of the GRASS import modules: `r.in.gdal`, `r.import` and `r.external` support a `band= ` argument to allow importing of selected bands. You probably want to read the man pages for these modules.

Comment: Thanks all, I was wanting to use i.rgb.his and other tools, but I guess you can't directly select an individual band with this tool, only those three listed above?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't quite understand. In the `i.rgb.his` module you explicitly set which band is red, which is green and which is blue. Can you explain what is missing here?

Comment: Yeah so what I mean is that if you put a 3 band raster into the inputs then it takes the first band, rather than letting you select which band you want as the input.

.........   I.e you can't say: ........    Red = 3Band.tif/Band_1   .......
Green = 3Band.tif/Band_2   .......
Blue = 3Band.tif/Band_3